# Maple fails to parse() spesial characters

Tags: parsing, special-characters, maple

I need to generate things like"
*F<sub>||;||</sub>(,t,t)*".
I try parse("F__||;|(,t,t)"). Maple returns "Error, incorrect syntax in parse: `;` unexpected (near 6th character of parsed string)"
Is there any way to get this *F<sub>||;||</sub>(,t,t)*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create names with special characters, you need to use single back quotes (also known as accent grave), which is the character under escape on most US keyboards.

```
parse("`F__||;||`(``,t,t)");
```